# MobX and deep observability

Tags: javascript, mobx

I'm trying to understand deep observability in MobX. 
In particular, in the following code I'd like the autorun to be called every time I run `setCommentCountForPost`, but currently it isn't.

How should I fix this code? And, observable on a property of Post is  enough to activate the autorun when I read the list in which the post is contained? (as I'm doing in the autorun)

I'm using MobX 5.

Edit: I discovered the code is working properly if I use the following call inside the autorun: `console.log(toJS(p.getPosts()));`.
This is interesting, but why, and how should I do if I only want to call getPosts()?

This is the code

```
import { useStrict, configure, autorun } from 'mobx';
import { toJS, observable, action, computed } from 'mobx';


configure({ enforceActions: true });

class Post {
    @observable commentCount = 0;

    setCommentCount(c) {
        this.commentCount = c;
    }
}

class PostList {
    @observable _posts = {};

    @action createPost(id) {
        this._posts[id] = new Post();
    }

    @action setCommentCountForPost(id, c) {
        this._posts[id].setCommentCount(c);
    }

    getPosts() {
        return this._posts;
    }
}

let p = new PostList();
p.createPost(1);


autorun(function test () {
    console.log(p.getPosts());
});


p.setCommentCountForPost(1, 22);
```

Answer (score 1):

MobX tracks property access, not value

in your example, the autorun function only tracking the _posts, but not the property of _posts, so if you change the _posts value the tracking function will worked

`console.log(toJS(p.getPosts()))` worked bacause of the toJS function in order to convert the observable value to normal value , it access the property of _posts.

if you hope the `p.getPosts()` worked, you should iteration access the property of _posts.